# Responsive navigation bar without Javascript, using only HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css, navigation, media-queries, responsive

I have an issue by making my navbar responsive. I understand that I need to use media queries but I am a beginner and I don't really know how to implement it as a list. Is it possible to do this without Javascript? Right now the code looks like this, a simple list:

```
<div id="nav">
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><b>HOME</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="works.html">WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO please provide the CSS you already make and what is exactly you want to do ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need media queries if you want to change some attributes for different viewports.  Check out the snippet below for a simple solution.

```html
    <html>

    <head>
      <style>
        body {
          padding: 0;
          margin: 0;
        }

        .navbar {
          display: flex;
          background-color: #FF5C5C;
          font-family: sans-serif;
        }

        ul {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          list-style: none;
        }

        ul>li>a {
          padding: 0 12px;
          color: white;
          font-size: 12px;
        }

        @media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
          ul>li>a {
            font-size: 16px;
            padding: 0 6px;
          }

          .navbar {
            background-color: #2689B9;
            background: linear-gradient(to right, #40B6C0 40%, #2689B9 80%);
          }

        }
      </style>
    </head>

    <body>

      <div class="navbar">
          <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="index.html"><b>HOME</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="works.html">WORKS</a></li>
            <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. The only thing is that the navbar is placed in the center while looking through responsive design mode on Chrome. How can I position it to the left?

Comment: Hmmm. I'm not getting that result.  It is docked to the left for me.  Maybe your page isn't set up for mobile viewports.  Try adding this inside your <head> tag `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, shrink-to-fit=no" />`

Comment: I managed to solve it, somehow there was an hidden element blocking it. however, thank you for your answer, it saved my day! :)